# why can't we call a function on a const object?

Tags: c++, objective-c++

the problem is in `main` where I want to call `set()` function on `display()` function which return a reference to const.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ostream;

class screen
{
public:
typedef string::size_type pos;
screen() = default;
screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) :height(ht), width(ht),contents(ht*wd, c){}
screen(pos ht, pos wd) :height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht*wd, ' '){}
char get()const{ return contents[cursor]; }
inline char get(pos r, pos c)const;
screen &move(pos r, pos c);
screen &set(char);
screen &set(pos r, pos c,char);
const screen& display(ostream &os)const;
    pos cursor;
    pos height, width;
    string contents;
};
const screen& screen::display(ostream &os)const
{
     os<< contents;
     return *this;
}

char screen::get(pos r, pos c)const
{
    pos row = r*width;
    return contents[row + c];
}
screen& screen::move(pos r, pos c)
{
    pos row = r*width;
    cursor = row + c;
    return *this;
}
screen& screen::set(char c)
{
    contents[cursor] = c;
    return *this;
}
screen& screen::set(pos r, pos c, char ch)
{
    pos row = r*width;
    contents[row + c] = ch;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    screen myscreen(50, 50,'0');
    myscreen.display(cout).set('#');//the problem is here!


    return 0;
}
```

I just want to know why `set('#')` cannot be called on `display(cout)` which returns a reference to const. 
It is possible to `set('#').display(cout)` but not `display(cout).set('#')`
How constness of an abject can have such a effect on a call?

Comment: What do you think `const` object is ? You can't change object, but your `set()` is `non-const`, so compiler thinks that you can modify object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call a member function, there is an implicit `this` pointer passing as a parameter to the function. In your case, the `this` pointer is `const`, and it can't be modified inside your `set` function. So it failed.

Answer (score 5):

I would advise reading more about what specifically `const` means in C++. The overall purpose of `const` is to prevent an object from being modified, and so since non-`const` methods have the potential to modify the object, they cannot be called on a `const` object or a `const` reference to an object.

Comment: oh I just realized yes the 'this pointer' is const and wanted to to call set on that and change that.